# aws-amplify subscription to appsync stops after 2 mins

Tags: nativescript, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

When subscribing to appsync using amplify using `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscription));` the subscription works for a while, but the I get socket closed error.

```
CONSOLE LOG [native code]: {
"[INFO] 24:12.893 MqttOverWSProvider": {
"errorCode": 8,
"errorMessage": "AMQJS0008I Socket closed.",
"uri": "wss://<uri>
```

The same subscription works in the appsync console without any issue and I get events as long as the subscription is running, but stops after around 2 mins on device.

code involved

```
let cs = await this.subscriptionService.appSubscriptions();
    this.sbscriptions = this.cs.subscribe({
      next: data => {
        console.dir(data);
              },
      error: error => console.dir(JSON.stringify(error)),
      close: () => console.log("closed")
 });
```

This part of code throws no error, and the error shown above is only visible when setting `LOG_LEVEL = DEBUG`

**NOTE** : The subscription does work for a while before this error shows up, and in that time I can see all the events that I trigger from console.

Comment: Have you made any headway with this issue? I've run into a similar issue, but my subscriptions seem to close immediately after they are opened. The error is rare and inconsistent. I've opened up two support tickets with the AWS support team and haven't heard anything back. So far my research has led me to: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=849420 a user talks about a limitation of 50 subscriptions per 24 hours per client, and opened 2 github issues related to it. Unfortunately this limit doesn't seem to be in their documentation, if it exists at all.

Comment: @Connor What platform are you using for this? There is a connect timeout in paho-mqtt. You can try increasing it. For my problem, I modified paho-mqtt and could make it work for around 30 mins on nativescript. Also I don't think such a limitation exists.