# NativeScript AWS AppSync Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, nativescript, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I've followed several AppSync tutorials for angular web, but trying to repeat the process in NativeScript has been more difficult. It looks like  [people have done it before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448935/aws-amplify-subscription-to-appsync-stops-after-2-mins) so any input from anyone who has gotten this to work would be awesome.

Following the same general procedure I did for a regular angular angular app, I attempted to use aws-appsync and nativescript-nodeify to attempt to make it nativescript-compatible. Adding nativescript-nodeify got rid of my initial error, but now I'm getting a new error:

The error I'm getting is:

```
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x100b9373c NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool, bool)
2   0x100bc4068 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x10056229c
4   0x184fcdfc0 <redacted>
JavaScript stack trace:
1   moduleDeclarationInstantiation@file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/non-terminating-link.js:71:26
2   link@[native code]
3   @[native code]
4   promiseReactionJob@[native code]
5   require@[native code]
6   anonymous@file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/non-terminating-link.js:71:26
7   evaluate@[native code]
8   moduleEvaluation@[native code]
9   @[native code]
10  promiseReactionJob@[native code]
11  require@[native code]
12  anonymous@file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/non-terminating-http-link.js:25:37
13  evaluate@[native code]
14  moduleEvaluation@[native code]
15  @[native code]
16  promiseReactionJob@[native code]
17  require@[native code]
18  anonymous@file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/index.js:21:42
19  evaluate@[native code]
20  moduleEvaluation@[native code]
21  @[native code]
22  promiseReactionJob@[native code]
23  require@[native code]
24  anonymous@file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/client.js:87:21
25  evaluate@[native code]
26  moduleEval<\M-b\M^@\M-&>
JavaScript error:
file:///app/tns_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/non-terminating-link.js:71:26: JS ERROR SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'print' is not found.
```

I'm getting an error when initializing AWSAppSyncConfig. The relevant code is below:

```
require('nativescript-nodeify');

const appSyncConfig = ...

import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';
import { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync/lib/link/auth-link';

...

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
   url: appSyncConfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
   region: appSyncConfig.aws_appsync_region,
   auth: {
      type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
         jwtToken: ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
});
```

The error message points to this line in non-terminating-link.js:

```
var linkUtils_1 = require("apollo-link/lib/linkUtils");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being related to a problem with compatibility between typescript 2.9.* and aws-appsync 1.3.4. I updated my typescript to 3.0.3 and it's working now